# have "exact" colors when printing

Tags: print-design, pantone, ink

When you have to make a **design for printing** you should always use **CMYK** color method, but when you need to print it the **result depends** on the **ink and the print setup** used in the specific printer shop.
*Here come the "invention" of the* **Pantone** colors standard, what I would like to know if **there are** some **alternatives to Pantone** or it is the only way **to have** an **"exact" color**

Comment: The "invention" is color management.

Comment: Color management. Panatone is not as exact as you think. How exact do you need? Do you have a spectral color target?

Comment: And Pantone is merely a brand. Granted the most popular, prolific brand, but still just a brand. There are others.... TOYO, Trumatch, Focoltone....

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BoldInflation :)

Comment: What I mean Is, when you are designing something that should be' printex do you leave It in CMYK or you choose a Pantone/something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you have to make a design for printing you should always use CMYK

Nope.

You could use RGB for example when the primary element is a photo, and when the print will be on a digital printer because it could probably need to use its own internal conversion for whatever inks the print is using.

Or you could need to use a duotone with spot inks. Or CMYK+Spot ink.

Or you could use a multi-channel file. etc.

> result depends on the ink and the print setup used in the specific printer shop

Close. The results depend on the specific setup (whatever that means) type of machine, type of paper, a brand of inks, plates,  quality control, color management control, even the operator's mood.

That is why we need to use a standardized color management workflow.

> Here comes the "invention" of the Pantone colors standard

Pantone is not a standard, it is a brand with standardized processes. Some elements are licensed to other actors, software companies, ink manufacturers.

> I would like to know if there are some alternatives to Pantone

Yes, Munsell color system, Toyo color system, RAL, Lab, HSK. Basically you can google Pantone alternative.

The point is this. Are the other suppliers in the chain using the system? In Japan, they would use Toyo, in Germany probably HSK.

> it is the only way to have an "exact" color

Two things here. Pantone system does not ensure the exact color either.

In the best-case scenario, you are using standardized components, including the substrate, but sometimes you can have for example a special paper that absorbs ink in a specific way so you will have a different color.

The color can vary even from sheet 1 to sheet 500 on small printshops, it can be a bit diluted, it can change density across the sheet, etc.

---

But the CORE of your question is not about Pantone. Pantone is a completely different system than RGB and CMYK. You started the case with CMYK, so the real answer is:

### A standardized Color Management Workflow.

In general on your side

- Good quality monitor
- Color managed to monitor and operating system
- Viewing conditions
- Professional-grade software
- Print profiles

In general on Printer's side

- Print profiles
- Plates
- Paper
- Ink
- Color bars
- Densitometer
- Viewing conditions
- Overall quality control

But the most important
- Knowledge and experience.

You can design things that will cause a lot of problems when printing if you do not have knowledge and experience.